# Cocos2D installation?

Tags: iphone, installation, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to install cocos2D but when I put it into terminal, I get the error:

Error: This script must be run as root in order to copy templates to /Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance,
Tate

EDIT 1:

I installed cocos2D and the project template show up but all of the files are red links and will not reveal in finder.  When I build I get 129 errors!  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could go ahead and

```
sudo ./install-templates.sh
```

and, assuming you are a sudoer, enter your password at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with the -u option and it should work fine. I had a similar issue when i installed as root as it said. I just re-ran the installer with the -u and it worked.

```
./install-templates.sh -u
```

Comment: sorry, but these are repeat posts.

Comment: yea thanks for marking mine down... it was only 6 months prior to the actual answer... try reading next time. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

./install-templates.sh -u in the terminal , I also face this problem with the help of this link , I easily solve the problem